# Subtract seconds in field from date query building Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I have a backend in Laravel 5.1 where I have 2 columns in my table: `seconds` and `date`.

I have to implement a function that select records where `date` is between `Carbon::now()` and `Carbon::now()->addMinute(60)-seconds` where seconds is a column in my database.

So select records if now is 07/11/2016 11:00 and in my table I have `date` 07/11/2016 10:50 and in my record `second` have 600.

So far I have tried this query:

```
DB::table('table')->whereBetween('table.date', array(Carbon::now() , Carbon::now()->addMinute(60)))
```

But how can I subtract second from a field table?

Answer (score -1):

You can try like this :-

For you reference [link](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

```html
echo $dt->subSeconds(61);
```

Comment: hello, yes, I know how subtract second in Carbon, but the problem is:
how subtract second that is in other field of same record?